# AuthError: Invalid login - 504 5.3.3 AUTH mechanism PLAIN not available

Tags: meteor, smtp

In my Meteor app, I have enabled `Accounts.config({sendVerificationEmail: true})` so that a verification email is sent post registration.

As soon as I create a new user,  I get the following exception on server side console.

```
I20150527-23:48:08.157(-7)?     - - - - -
I20150527-23:48:08.155(-7)?     at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:76:1)
I20150527-23:48:08.154(-7)? Exception while invoking method 'createUser' AuthError: Invalid login - 504 5.3.3 AUTH mechanism PLAIN not available
```

I went back and checked the details of AUTH supported.

```
[mtikmani@host1]$ telnet localhost smtp
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 host1 ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4; Thu, 28 May 2015 06:50:47 GMT
ehlo  <SMTP relayHOST>
250-<host1> Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
**250-AUTH GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5**
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
```

Looks like on my host `AUTH PLAIN` is not supported and thus the exception. I can't possibly add the `AUTH PLAIN` as this is maintained by IT guys, and they won't be willing to change it to support `AUTH PLAIN`.

Q: 
a. Is there a way out?
b. Can't I directly use `/usr/sbin/sendmail` which is propertly configured by IT guys and can be used to send email?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the USERNAME:PASSWORD from my MY_URL env variable and now I am able to send email!!

Comment: I got this error Relaying denied: You must check for new mail before sending mail.